# Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am developing a slider to set my budget and would like to achieve the value which I set in slider1.php. However, when I tried using the code below, I encountered an error 
"Notice: Undefined index: slideStatus in C:\xampp\htdocs\1204763e\slider1\slider1.php on line 4
Thank you , says the PHP file"

In slide.php, I inserted this set of code:

```
     <html>
    <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function ajax_post(val){

        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var url = "slider1.php";
        var ss = document.getElementById('sliderStatus').innerHTML = val;
        var vars = "sliderStatus="+ss;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);

        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
        }
        // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>

    <input type="range" name="slide" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="2" onChange="ajax_post(this.value)" />
    <br /><br />
    <span id="sliderStatus">50</span>
    <br/><br/>

    <div id="status"></div>

    </body>
    </html>



In slider1.php, I inserted this set of code:

    <?php 
    echo 'Thank you '. $_GET['slideStatus'] . ', says the PHP file';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to try to access "slideStatus" but you are posting "sliderStatus".

Comment: Do you know at which part of the code must I insert &yen; if I wish to display the yen sign in front of the value?

Comment: there : `var ss = document.getElementById('sliderStatus').innerHTML = '&yen;'+val`

Comment: sorry but I still could achieve that result after I add '&yen;'+ before val. Is there any other way?